# Database schema validation with EclipseLink

Tags: java, eclipselink

With EclipseLink/JPA 2.0, I could not find a way to check the database schema upon startup. It can only create or drop and create tables.
Hibernate automatically performs schema validation when `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate`, and this is really cool.
Any chance to achieve this with EclipseLink?

Comment: It's been almost 4 years since this question was first asked.  I wonder if EclipseLink has added a persistence.xml setting to do this validation check yet?  As @ochedru mentions, Hibernate has this ability.  Recently, I found OpenJPA also has this ability too: openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings=validate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a persistence.xml option for it yet (please log a bug), but you can do this through the IntegrityChecker.

Use a SessionCustomizer to configure the IntegrityChecker on the Session to check the database.  It will validate the table names and columns names match the database.

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm trying to avoid an exception when the table for an entity class does not exist (because EclipseLink is configured with `eclipselink.ddl-generation=create-tables` in my case).